# Converting integer to binary: program breaks at the number 1024

Tags: java

I have a program whose intention is to take in a decimal integer and return the binary value.

```
  public static int returnBinary(int number) {
            int current;
            int digit = 1;
            int result = 0;
            while (number > 0) {
                current = number % 2;
                number = number/2;
                result = result + current * digit;
                digit = digit * 10;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

This program works perfectly until it reaches the value 1024, for which it returns the value: 1410065408

Larger values than 1024 also do not work. I noticed 1023 in binary is 1111111111, which may be relevant as to why 1024 does not work.

Comment: try returning your result as a String, instead of an int.

Comment: So `result` is a decimal `int` but containing only `0` and `1`? Maximum value for `int` is about 2.1 billion - you're likely exceeding that. Anything wrong with [`Integer.toBinaryString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)).

Comment: Got it, I would have to use long. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use long, use a data structure that can actually represent a reasonably-sized binary array (such as string, List<Boolean>, or Boolean[]).

Comment: But that would only support about 19 digits - still not enough for the 32 bits of an `int`.

Comment: No, don't use long - use a string. You're trying to return the *textual* representation of a number in a particular base. The way to return *text* is to use a string.

Comment: @Ironcache or something sensible, like a `BitSet`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes that works (though, I debate the assertion that any of the mentioned are not sensible).  The point is long is not what is desired here.

Comment: The most efficient way to represent a sequence of bits (0 or 1) is to use a type of variable that can store the data as a sequence of bits. One such type is `int`. Hold on, that's what you already have!

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense. I would want to create a String and simply concatenate it with the value of current.

Comment: @BoristheSpider *"Anything wrong with Integer.toBinaryString."* maybe it is not as  educational as this homework might be intended... ;o)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to assign a value which is higher than the `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. In Java it is `2.147.483.647` and the binary value of `1.111.111.111` might be 1023 in decimal, but it is around half of the `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Anything higher is not representable in `Integer`. You might want to return a `String` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can return String rather than the integer, please find the string implementation below.

```
public static String returnBinary(int number) {
    String result = "";
    int digit;
    while (number > 0) {
        digit = number & 0X1;
        result = digit+result;
        number = number >> 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct in the terms of implementing the solution for homework (otherwise, the comment on the question to use `toBinaryString()` is likely best).  So, given that this is in the context of homework, you might not want to just outright solve it for them.

Answer (score -1):

In binary 1024 is `10000000000` however max value for an int is `2 147 483 647` so  you have exceeded the maximum size

Comment: The _compiler_ reacts strangely? This is both vague and wrong.

Comment: It is not *compiler* that reacts, and reaction is not strange, it is simple integer overflow which happens at *runtime*.